# How to keep continuous ImageView and hide the other views?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view, android-framelayout

I am working with a designer for the first time.

And he wants me to implement this complex screen transition.

[image]

The current Screen doesn't move. But the new screen come from the right side and then it is stacked.

The problem is this. The ImageView which is animation must run in all the screens continuously(no move) and repeat the animation. So, when the new screen comes from the right side. The ImageView must be alive. But the rest are hidden by the new screen.

At first, I thought I need to make `MainActivity` which has `screen star animation` with white or transparent background. And then, use half-transparent background color(pink) for the fragments.

However, I checked the video that designer sent me. And I found out that the texts and images, buttons are hidden and just the star keeps moving.

The way I am implementing is totally wrong because you can see everything in the previous screen, not only the star but also the texts and buttons and also the color becomes thicker.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can use view flipper in order to achieve this kind of stuff https://www.journaldev.com/10429/android-viewflipper-example-tutorial

Comment: It looks different/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It's kind of difficult feature to implement.

You can use FrameLayout or just put the view as the most front view with half transparency(maybe around 15% opacity).

Then, it looks like it's behind of all the views.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you are needing this transition , but the best way to achieve it is using `viewpager` and customizing fragment transition animation using  `setPageTransformer`

here is a [link](https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4) to understand how it works and how to implement it . you just have to get how to control view's and element's visibility using `setAlpha()` for the fade and with a bit of work you will achieve what you want

Comment: I think it is not ViewPager. Because, the old screen must be stacked over the current screen.